# How to loop collections in LINQ and pass on data

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

How do i do this in LINQ - So i dont have to use ForEach or loops?

I can't seem to figure out how to pass a list when some condition is met and this way loop the collection with LINQ.

```
products.ForEach(delegate(CustomEcomProducts p)
{                            
  p.VariantProducts = variants.Where(prod => prod.VariantParentID == p.ProductID)
                        .ToList();
});
```

Comment: Just for interest. Why you dont like loops?

Comment: I do like loops, i'm just pretty new at LINQ and was sure there was a way to do this without loops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not what LINQ is for. The **Q** in LINQ stands for "Query".

The best/cleanest/most readable way to do this is the following:

```
foreach(var product in products)
    product.VariantProducts = variants.Where(x => x.VariantParentID == p.ProductID)
                                      .ToList();
```